# Some records are reverted back to old value in SQL Server 2016 Bidirectional Replication

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have successfully setup bidirectional replication for 4 servers, says A, B, C, and D with the following configuration:
1. Server A acts as Distributor, Publisher for B, C, and D, also as a Subscriber for B, C, and D.
2. Server B, C and D acts as Publisher and Subscriber for server A.
3. they all are connected to a 1-2MB VPN.
and they are all works well until this week I found a weird behavior in two servers. Some of the records are reverted back to old value after couple seconds. I have checked the data was replicated, and then reverted back randomly. I have no idea what caused the problem, I have set @loopback_detection to true during the creation of all subscribers. Does anyone experienced the same or know how to solve it? Thank you.

Achmad Mulyadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not an answer to my own question rather a better solution to eliminate most of the problem in bi-directional replication, "MERGE REPLICATION".
With Merge Replication you can:

1. Do two way replication even in Standard Edition.
2. Offer the easiest way to resolve conflict between servers
3. Either remote snapshot or "local" snapshot is supported. "Local"
   means, you can copy a big snapshot through FTP or even an external
   HDD and copy the snapshot file to another server manually.
4. The most stable way to replicate database in multi-master
   replication.